# Bootstrap fixed header and footer with collapsible sidebar

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm working on a layout with a fixed header and footer in the content area with a collapsible sidebar. Currently it's working pretty well but there are some small quirks which I can't seem to figure out.

1. When the sidebar is toggled shut the body content snaps to it's 100% width and shows a scroll bar on the bottom until it's finished collapsing. I want the content to either have it's width tween like the sidebar or just have overflow-x hidden so it doesn't show the scroll bar at all.
2. I want the footer to be a dynamic height. I will be loading different content in there based on database queries and the number of entries I pull will determine the height of the footer. Currently it's locked at 60px.

As for the first problem, I've tried adding overflow-x hidden to various elements without success. The second problem has been a little more complicated. I've tried some CSS calc() operations but nothing has worked so far.

Here is my code, if you want to test it out you'll need **bootstrap.min.css**, **bootstrap.min.js** and **jquery.js**. I tried setting up a Codepen or Bootply example but it wouldn't work with the collapsible sidebar.

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">

    <title>Calendar</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap Core CSS -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Custom CSS -->
    <link href="css/frame.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->

</head>

<body>

    <div id="wrapper">
        <!-- Sidebar -->
        <div id="sidebar-wrapper">
            <ul class="sidebar-nav">
                <li class="sidebar-brand">
                    <a href="#">
                        Start Bootstrap
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Dashboard</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Shortcuts</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Overview</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Events</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">About</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Services</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Contact</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <!-- /#sidebar-wrapper -->

        <header>header</header>
        <!-- Page Content -->
        <div id="page-content-wrapper">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-12">

                        <h1>Simple Sidebar</h1>
                        <p>This template has a responsive menu toggling system. The menu will appear collapsed on smaller screens, and will appear non-collapsed on larger screens. When toggled using the button below, the menu will appear/disappear. On small screens, the page content will be pushed off canvas.</p>
                        <p>Make sure to keep all page content within the <code>#page-content-wrapper</code>.</p>
                        <a href="#menu-toggle" class="btn btn-default" id="menu-toggle">Toggle Menu</a>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- /#page-content-wrapper -->
        <footer>footer</footer>
    </div>
    <!-- /#wrapper -->

    <!-- jQuery -->
    <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>

    <!-- Bootstrap Core JavaScript -->
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Menu Toggle Script -->
    <script>
    $("#menu-toggle").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#wrapper").toggleClass("toggled");
        $("header").toggleClass("toggled");
        $("footer").toggleClass("toggled");
    });
    </script>

</body>

</html>
```

CSS (from Frame.css)

```
/* Header Footer Styles */
header {
    width: 100%;
    height: 60px;
    background: red;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
}
header.toggled {
    width: calc(100% - 250px);
}

footer {
    width: 100%;
    height: 60px;
    background: red;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
}
footer.toggled {
    width: calc(100% - 250px);
}

/* Toggle Styles */

#wrapper {
    padding-left: 0;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
}
#wrapper.toggled {
    padding-left: 250px;
}

#sidebar-wrapper {
    z-index: 1000;
    position: fixed;
    left: 250px;
    width: 0;
    height: 100%;
    margin-left: -250px;
    overflow-y: auto;
    background: #000;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

#wrapper.toggled #sidebar-wrapper {
    width: 250px;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}

#page-content-wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    margin-top:60px;
    max-height: calc(100% - 120px);
    overflow-y: auto;
}

#wrapper.toggled #page-content-wrapper {
    position: absolute;
    margin-right: -250px;
    width: calc(100% - 250px);
}

/* Sidebar Styles */

.sidebar-nav {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 250px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
}

.sidebar-nav li {
    text-indent: 20px;
    line-height: 40px;
}

.sidebar-nav li a {
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #999999;
}

.sidebar-nav li a:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff;
    background: rgba(255,255,255,0.2);
}

.sidebar-nav li a:active,
.sidebar-nav li a:focus {
    text-decoration: none;
}

.sidebar-nav > .sidebar-brand {
    height: 65px;
    font-size: 18px;
    line-height: 60px;
}

.sidebar-nav > .sidebar-brand a {
    color: #999999;
}

.sidebar-nav > .sidebar-brand a:hover {
    color: #fff;
    background: none;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a bit hacky, but for problem 1, you could try adding the following to your click function:

```
$("body").css("overflow-x", "hidden");
setTimeout(function(){$("body").css("overflow-x", "auto");}, 1500);
```

For problem 2, you could just remove the height.

**Update:** Sorry, I think I misunderstood problem 2. The only solution I can think of (again a bit of a hack) is to have jquery calculate and set it when the page loads:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var currentFooterHeight = $('footer').css('height');
  var newContentHeight = 'calc(100vh - 60px - ' + currentFooterHeight + ')';
  $('#page-content-wrapper').css('height', newContentHeight);
})
```

[Updated Bootply](http://www.bootply.com/lRSKFC6Fnc)

Comment: Great solutions! If you have a minute could you please help me understand how those js functions work? For the first one it looks like it sets the body overflow x to hidden then back to auto after a timeout period. Is there any reason I wouldn't always want it always hidden if that fixes the problem? The height function makes sense but I am wondering where you get the 100vh - 60px from. Thank you for the help!

Comment: You've got the first one right. You could just set it to hidden, but if you have any content that is wider than the window (especially on a small device like a phone), users won't be able to see it. Personally, I prefer to set it back to auto unless there is another reason to permanently hide it.

Comment: For the second one, 100vh is 100% of the view height. From here, I minus the height of the header, and the current height of the footer, which leaves me with the height of the content in between.

Comment: That all makes sense. Thank you for all the help!